# passing array of variables to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have a C function which needs a large amount of variables to be passed, so I came to the idea of "packing" them all in a single array (matrix of variables). The point is, these variables are of a very different type, some int, some arrays (strings and vectors), and many of them float. Is there a way to leave unspecified the type of data stored into the matrix? (I unsuccessfully explored the void "data type")

Comment: May be use a [`struct`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language))?

Comment: Why don't you use a struct for all your data and pass a struct pointer to your function? Much less data to copy.

Comment: ..and possibly a pointer to it, if copying the struct is expensive, undesired or even dangerous in your design.

Comment: Wow, structures sound promising, I'll give it a look! Thx

Comment: You're talking about array of unions, but you want to use structs.

Comment: Define "large".  More than 10?  More than 20?  Are they logically related to each other (i.e., *attributes* of a single data item) or not?  What does your function do with all these variables?  Don't use a `struct` type to collect attributes that aren't otherwise related to each other *just* to avoid passing lots of parameters.

Comment: "Is there a way to leave unspecified the type of data stored into the matrix?'  There is a way, yet how then does your function determine what data it received as it is unspecified?

Answer (score 8):

The elements of an array are always of a single type, that's the point.

Collecting variables of multiple types is the job for a structure, i.e. a `struct`.

This is a quite common way to solve this particular problem. If the structure becomes large, you might find it convenient to pass a *pointer* to an instance of it, rather than copying the entire thing in the call.

Comment: Why not an array of pointers of type void and use index to identify type inside the function?

Comment: @Ziezi 1) It involves extra dereference. 2.) It is less type safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use va_list but struct is the best way to do it

Comment: Just mentioning `va_list` is not enough. There needs to be a way to identify parameters, and your answer doesn't explain that at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

enum type {
        INT,
        FLOAT,
        PCHAR,
};

struct any_type {
        enum type type_;
        union {
                int int_;
                float float_;
                char* pchar_;
        };
};

#define MYSIZE 10

void process(size_t size, struct any_type* array)
{
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                switch(array[i].type_) {
                        case INT :
                                printf("INT: %d\n", array[i].int_);
                                break;
                        case FLOAT :
                                printf("FLOAT: %f\n", array[i].float_);
                                break;
                        case PCHAR :
                                printf("PCHAR: %s\n", array[i].pchar_);
                                break;
                        default:
                                printf("UNKNOWN TYPE PROVIDED\n");
                                break;
                }
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct any_type *array;
  array = malloc(MYSIZE*(sizeof(struct any_type)));

  array[0].type_ = INT;
  array[0].int_ = 10;

  array[1].type_ = FLOAT;
  array[1].float_ = 2.5;

  array[2].type_ = PCHAR;
  array[2].pchar_ = "hello char";

  process(3, array);

  return 0;
}
```

You can extend type and union as needed. However using nameless unions require -std=c11.

Comment: I'm not sure this much complexity is needed. `union` lacks compile time type safety that simple pointer to struct would offer.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above:

Needing to pass a large number of parameters<sup>1</sup> to a function *can* be a sign that there is a problem in your design - your function may be trying to do too many things at once, and you would be better off refactoring it into several smaller functions, each of which only takes a subset of the parameters.

Assuming that's not the case, how are your parameters logically related to each other?  Can they be considered *attributes* of a single data item?  For example, a person may be described by the following attributes: surname, given name, birth date, sex.  These can be collected together into a single `struct` type such as

```
#include <time.h>

struct person {
  char *surname; 
  char *name;
  struct tm birthdate; // struct tm defined in time.h
  char sex;
};

void write_to( struct person *p )
{
  p->surname = strdup( "McGillicuddy" ); 
  p->name = strdup( "Aloysius" );
  p->sex = 'M';
  p->birthdate.tm_year = 32; // tm_year starts at 1900, so this is 1932
  p->birthdate.tm_mon = 11;  // december
  p->birthdate.tm_day = 1;   
};

int main( void )
{
  struct person p;
  ...
  write_to( &p );
  ...
}
```

Note that members of `struct` types can themselves be `struct` types - [`struct tm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html) is a type defined in `time.h` that specifies a datetime value using multiple attributes.

Some notes on syntax:

When you want to access a member of a `struct` instance, use the `.` operator.  When you want to access a member of a `struct` through a *pointer*, use the `->` operator.  In the function `write_to`, `p` is a pointer to `struct person`, so to access each member of `p` we use `->`.  The `birthdate` member is an *instance* of `struct tm`, not a pointer, so we use the `.` operator to access each member of `birthdate`.

`p->m` is equivalent to `(*p).m`.

Like I said in my comment, you should *not* collect otherwise unrelated items into a `struct` type *just* to reduce the number of parameters being passed to a function.  They should all be attributes of a more complex type.  Some other examples of what I mean:

```
// A node in a list
struct node {
  data_t data; // for some data type data_t;
  struct node *next;
  struct node *prev;
};

// A street address
struct addr {
  char *number; // to handle things like 102A, 102B
  char *street;
  char *city;
  char state[3];
  char *zip;
};
```

It's possible that you're really passing only a couple of distinct data items to your function, each of which is composed of a lot of different attributes.  Take a step back and look at your variables and see how they relate to each other.

---

1. "Large" depends on context, and of course there are always exceptions to any rule, but in general passing more than 7 distinct, unrelated parameters is a sign you may need to refactor your function into several smaller functions.

Comment: I'm giving struct a go (trying right now). I get your concern about the amount of data, but this function is to perform a physical simulation which just requires several physical variables, it won't be easy to reduce this number  :-(